# When launching an application using applescript, I am not getting the splash screen

Tags: c++, applescript, splash-screen, nsapplescript

When launching an application using applescript, I am not getting the splash screen

I am trying to launch an application and open a file using applescript.
I am using this script in my c++ project. The application launcher code goes
some what like this:

```
do shell script \"osascript -e 'tell application \"Finder\" to open POSIX file \"
<file_path>\" with the application \"<application_path>\"'\r\"".
```

I am sorry that, i don't remember the exact command right now.
I am using `NSAppleScript` to run the script in my project. The application is 
launched corretly. But splash screen in missing. (Application that I am trying 
to launch is `adobe illustrator`.

I had also tried the system command.
 `system("open \"<application_path>\" --args \"<file_path>\"")`.

By this way, I was able to get the splash screen working, But, if the application was already running, it won't attempt to open the file.
There might be some error in the code that I posted.

Comment: I was able to make it work with the help of launch command in script.
tell application AppPath to launch

Answer (score 2):

Use the command **open** with the **-a** option like this:

```
open -a <application_path> <file_path>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the command. It opened the file in illustrator the first time. But if the illustrator is already running, it won't open the new file, instead it brings the application to foreground.